# Mathematical induction proving positive integers

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Prove that if $n$ is a positive integer, then $7^n-1$ is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: do you mean $$n^7-1$$ is divisible by $6$?

Comment: If he does it's not true. $2^7-1=127$ is not divisible by $6$. Perhaps you mean $7^n-1$. But in that case it's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant this
$$7^n-1$$ is divisible by $6$

This can be factored like this
$$(7-1)(7^{n-1}+7^{n-2}+...+1)$$
which is obviously divisible by $6$.